# How to post id on checkbox in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to make a simple pagination page. This is regarding delete function. I have a checkbox that user can choose to delete a row. May I know how to *post/get* the id of the row if user click on next link? In my case, the id will be duplicate if user click on the checkbox. Below are my codes,

**jQuery**

```
var cbNew = [],
cbAdd = [];

function addId(checkBox){
    cbAdd = cbAdd.concat(checkBox);
    console.log(cbAdd);
}

$(document).on("click", ".checkBox", function(){
    var cb = [];
    $('.checkBox:checked').each(function(){
        cb.push($(this).val());
    });

    if(cb.length > 0) { 
        addId(cb);
        $('#delete').fadeIn(); 
    } else {
        $('#delete').fadeOut();
    }
});

//Link on Next Page
$(".nextPage").click(getFunct);

function getFunct(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
    row = getURLParameter(url, 'startrow'),
    cbNew = cbNew;
    getParam(row,url);
}

function getParam(param1,param2){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: 
        {
            row : param1,
            url : param2,
            cbNew : cbNew
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
        addId(cbNew);
    });
}
```

This is the output if I click on multiple checkbox on same page `console.log(cbAdd);`

```
["25", "25", "26", "25", "26", "27"]
```

If I click one checkbox on page 1 and one checkbox on page 2, it get the id correcltly

```
["25", "59"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maintaining two arrays, one capture all checked checkbox values ie cb and concatenating these to another array called cbAdd, here you are duplicating values.

lets use single array cbAdd as below -

```
$(document).on("change", ".checkBox", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var index = cbAdd.indexOf(value);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      cbAdd.push(value); //put value
    } else {
       cbAdd.splice(index, 1);//remove value
    }
    if(cbAdd.length > 0) { 
        $('#delete').fadeIn(); 
    } else {
        $('#delete').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @BhushanKawadkar. You made it work! May I know regarding this line `var index = cbAdd.indexOf(value);`. What does it do?

Comment: `var index = cbAdd.indexOf(value);` will search value inside cbAdd and return it's position in cbAdd. This I have used to know whether value is present or not. `indexOf` will return position if value present and return -1 if not present.